# Почему клик по label срабатывает 2 раза

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вывожу текст 'click' по клику на label с классом .product-switcher

```js
document.querySelector('.product-switcher').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('click');
})
```

```html
<label class="product-switcher">
  <input type="checkbox">
   <div class="product-switcher-current"></div>
   <div class="product-switcher-left">2,5 кг</div>
   <div class="product-switcher-right">25 кг </div>
</label>
```

Почему клик срабатывает дважды?

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, клик по `label` вызывает клик также на вложенном `input` и это событие поднимается.

Comment: @zhurof: почему не в ответе, а в комментарии?

Comment: @UModeL , отвлекли. Не успел ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Двойное срабатывание происходит потому, что `<label>`, в данном случае, является одновременно и управляющим элементом и родителем для `<input>`. Поэтому первый click - это по самому элементу, а второй - это всплытие от `<input>`.

```js
document.querySelector('.product-switcher').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('click label');
});
document.querySelector('.product-switcher input').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('click input');
});
```

```html
<label class="product-switcher">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div class="product-switcher-current"></div>
    <div class="product-switcher-left">2,5 кг</div>
    <div class="product-switcher-right">25 кг</div>
</label>
```

Чтобы предотвратить двойное срабатывание, нужно прервать всплытие от `<input>`-а:

```js
document.querySelector('.product-switcher').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('click label');
});
document.querySelector('.product-switcher input').addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  ev.stopPropagation();
  console.log('click input');
});
```

```html
<label class="product-switcher">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div class="product-switcher-current"></div>
    <div class="product-switcher-left">2,5 кг</div>
    <div class="product-switcher-right">25 кг</div>
</label>
```

Comment: А почему label срабатывает дважды?

Comment: @InDevX: срабатывает не *label*, а обработчик события.

Comment: Не суть. Имел ввиду почему label срабатывает дважды?

Comment: @InDevX: *внимательно* изучите ответ и примеры.